# Using a For-loop to find a date in a range of dates [Google Sheets]

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I am new to scripting and cannot understand why this For-loop is not working for me.  Any help would be immensely appreciated.

What I am trying to achieve:

- In the sheet 'Today' in cell D4 is a date. The specific format of the date is '25/02/2020'.
- In another sheet, 'Future' is a list of dates that go from cells B8 and to the bottom of column B.
- I want to compare the date from cell  D4 with all the dates in B8:B of the 'Future' sheet, and if it finds a match, I want it to run the very last line of script below (that isn't just a closing bracket).
- In the 'Future' sheet in cell B9 is the same date, with the same format of '25/02/2020', so the script should be able to find a match.

Thanks.

```
function onEdit(e) {

//This IF statement ensures that this onEdit macro only runs when cell B2 in the sheet 'Today' is edited.
  if (
    e.source.getSheetName() == "Today" &&
    e.range.columnStart == 2 &&
    e.range.columnEnd == 2 &&
    e.range.rowStart == 2 &&
    e.range.rowEnd == 2 
  ) { 

  //Defines the relevant sheets as variables:
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var Today = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Today");  
    var Future = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Future");  
  //Variables needed for the below:
    var futuredates = Future.getRange('B8:B').getValues();
    var Date = Today.getRange("D4").getValue();

  //CANNOT GET THIS TO WORK:
    for (var i = futuredates.length - 1; i > 0; i--) { 
     if (futuredates[i][0] == Date ) {   

        //This line is just to see if the above works::
        Today.insertRowsBefore(6, 1);

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pattern 1:

From your question, it is found that the same format of date is used for the cells of `D4` and `B8:B`. In this pattern, using this, the date is used as the string value.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

##### From:

```
var futuredates = Future.getRange('B8:B').getValues();
var Date = Today.getRange("D4").getValue();
```

##### To:

```
var futuredates = Future.getRange('B8:B').getDisplayValues();
var Date = Today.getRange("D4").getDisplayValue();
```

- In your script, `if (futuredates[i][0] && Date && futuredates[i][0].getTime() == Date.getTime() ) {` might be suitable.

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the date is used as the date object.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

##### From:

```
if (futuredates[i][0] == Date ) {
```

##### To:

```
if (futuredates[i][0] && Date && futuredates[i][0].getTime() == Date.getTime() ) {
```

### Note:

- By above modification, when the if statement is `true`, `Today.insertRowsBefore(6, 1);` is run.

### References:

- [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)
- [getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)